# I can't stop monerod (monero daemon)

Tags: monerod, daemon, tor

So I'm using 0.12.2.0 on tails 3.7.1 and running a local node (through tor).
I use these commands to start the daemon:

*sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -m tcp --dport 18081 -j ACCEPT*

and then

*DNS_PUBLIC=tcp TORSOCKS_ALLOW_INBOUND=1 torsocks ./monerod --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --no-igd --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --block-sync-size 10 --data-dir /data/dir*

Whenever I try to stop the daemon gracefully it won't stop

```
2018-06-13 17:15:43.881     77f8aea0c700    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Stop signal sent
2018-06-13 17:15:50.147     77f8aea0c700    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Blockchain saved
2018-06-13 17:15:54.879     77f8aea0c700    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Stop signal sent
2018-06-13 17:16:30.140     77f8aea0c700    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Stop signal sent
```

I use *stop_daemon* or *exit*

I'd like to update my bitmonero.log but I'm not sure it would compromise my opsec, update me on that.

Comment: It's probably timing out on a connect operation. monero sets a 5 second timeout to connect, but AFAIK torsocks' connect just blocks for a long time in some cases. You can use gdb to check where it's stuck: gdb monerod `pidof monerod`, then thread apply all bt.